# What NoSQL data store to use for 3 billion rows dominated by writes

Tags: sharding, throughput, document-database, nosql

I want users to view, and search, the titles of pages they visited on my site, from any device.
Given the requirements below, **which NoSQL would do the job and would make users happy**?
Data sizing: 3 Billion rows (6M users, keeping a history of 500 titles/user).  ~1.5TB.

row/document structure: [ userId(GUID), pageId(GUID), viewedTime, pageTitle(max 160 chars)  ]
**Writes** (expected write rate: 2,000 viewed pages/sec):
When a page is viewed by a user, A new row will be created, unless the user previously viewed the page, and I'll just update the viewedTime of an existing row.

**Queries** (expected query rate: 300/sec):
 1. Retrieving 100-500 most recent titles by userId (the scanning for a keyword with String.indexOf()).
 2. Retrieving a row by userId AND pageID.
 3. Cleanup - A batch job to reduce to 500 titles per userId by removing the older ones.

Notes:

- Would be happy for a Store that includes a caching layer.
- I'm okay with an occasional data lose. And fine with eventual consistency.
- The amount of data might grow x10 so I need to be able to scale (therefore horizontal scalability?)
- There are millions of distinct pages, so to avoid a join I thought keep the title in each row.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you could go with Cassandra. It is write optimised and when performing read operations you can specify how up to date you want the data to have. And if you’ll go with the lowest consistency configuration for reads, it will also perform quite well. Otherwise reading is quite slow for cassandra.

Comment: I agree, Cassandra will work well for this if the read speed is acceptable. It is highly scalable for writes for sure.